# Excel fill dates except Sunday

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to fill a series of dates but Skip Sundays. When I right click the fill handle it only has weekday option, which will skip Saturday too. That's not what I need. How do I approach this? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer more suitable for my situation.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 1))=7,INDIRECT("A" & ROW() -1) + 2, INDIRECT("A" & ROW() -1 ) +1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

**Method 1:**
You could fill all days and in an adjacent column add a WEEKDAY function pointing at the dates column. Next, AutoFilter the weekday column to show Sundays only and delete all results.

**Method 2:**
Instead of the simple WEEKDAY function, you could define: `=IF(WEEKDAY(A2,1)=1,"Sunday",A2)`
Fill it to all cells in a neighboring column. After that select all rows, and use the "remove duplicates" function in the "data" tab. Select the column you just filled and when all duplicates (Sundays) are deleted, only one line (the first occurrence of "Sunday") will remain which you'll have to delete manually.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! I just can't remove duplicates or delete extra rows since there are data I need to keep. But I really appreciate your help